# Debian 11 - grub: Secure boot forbids loading module from (hd1,gpt5)/grub/x86_ 64-efi/exfat.mod

Tags: boot, debian, grub, secure-boot

When booting up, my screen flashes with a bunch of errors, reporting that some grub modules couldn't be loaded due to Secure Boot, e.g.:

```
Secure boot forbids loading module from (hd1,gpt5)/grub/x86_ 64-efi/minix.mod
Secure boot forbids loading module from (hd1,gpt5)/grub/x86_ 64-efi/hfs.mod  
Secure boot forbids loading module from (hd1,gpt5)/grub/x86_ 64-efi/exfat.mod
```

I realize that Secure Boot requires kernel/grub modules to be signed, but I thought that should be taken care of by the distribution (Debian in this case). I know that Debian has [a nice page on signing modules](https://wiki.debian.org/SecureBoot), so theoretically I could sign all of those myself, but I'm just wondering if it's the right way to approach this.

One piece of information that may be of some importance is that I'm running two partitions: encrypted `/` and plain `/boot`. Those messages are printed by grub right before the passphrase prompt appears.

I scanned the web for a fix, but haven't really found any, so any insight is appreciated.

---

Edit: If you want to reproduce my issue on your machine, go into `/etc/default/grub` and

1. Change line: `GRUB_TIMEOUT=5` to `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0`
2. Add line: `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=3`

After that, of course run `# update-grub` and reboot. Without those steps, instead of the errors I talked about, you would have seen a normal grub menu. I did all of this on my PC, to skip the menu and boot directly to Debian.

---

Edit #2: For some reason I confused kernel and grub modules so right now I'm not even sure if the linked Debian wiki page is relevant in any way. Edited the original question where it was needed.

Comment: Those are not kernel modules. They are GRUB modules.

Comment: @DanielB Thanks for pointing that out, edited the question and removed the (now irrelevant) tag